# limit tor socks server to a certain hidden service

Tags: onion-services, socks

I have tor running on a pc, with its socks server listening on localhost port 9050.

I would like to limit the socks server in this way:

socks requests (from clients) should be allowed only for a given hidden service url, and blocked for any other request.

Is this possible with tor? How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, this cannot be done within Tor.

You'd need to run some SOCKS shim to filter out requests that aren't explicitly for that onion address which should be a simple (for a programmer) task if the application using the SOCKSPort is using SOCKS5h or SOCKS4a (if it's not, it's a bit more involved) but it would need to be done *outside* of Tor.

Comment: I am using SOCKS4a. Can you suggest a SOCKS proxy or another kind of "shim" to filter out requests?

Comment: The process would really be implementing SOCKS4a/SOCKS5 well enough to mimick enough functionality for the client(s)  to be able to use it, then when they provide you with *where* to connect check it against the list and either fail the connection by sending the client a response, or allow it to continue.

Answer (score 0):

Well, using **just** SOCKS it's impossible - whatever the software is applied: the reason is in the SOCKS protocol nature. It's not like HTTP proxy that works like "I want to connect to http://xy.z via GET http://xy.z -> Ok, here it is" - it's working by providing *pipes*, so the "jailbreak scenarios" can be exploited here with Auto-mapping hosts to local network - like 10.0.0.0/16, so SOCKS server will get a request like "I want to connect to 10.0.11.12 port 1234", not like "I want to connect to not-whitelisted-onion-service.onion port 1234". If you will not use automapping - well, it still be quite a work with an intermediate proxy to filter the URL list. But keep in mind - a jailbreak here is still possible if, for example, the whitelisted service makes some proxy-like stuff - you won't see the URL's. So - if you want to be 100% sure to allow access to your **own** hidden service - use HTTPS for it with an enforced HTTPS with self-generated certificate and a SSL proxy - and on your SSL proxy drop **any** traffic that is not goes through with your server's certificate(you'll have to load a copy of that cert to your SSL proxy). Only that particular solution will ensure the strictness **and** won't break end-user experiences much.